How to install CDO on Alpine:3.20 docker image
I am trying to set up a Docker container based on Alpine Linux.
The container needs to have Python 3.12.4 installed with Dask and Zarr. I had to install it from the source, and it went well. However, I need to install also cdo (Climate Data Operators). But I am not able to do it.
Note that I need a docker image with no vulnerabilities, so I am trying to use Alpine as the base image. Previously, I had a working env using Ubuntu:24.04, but I could not get rid of the following vulnerability:
NAME             INSTALLED     FIXED-IN TYPE    VULNERABILITY   SEVERITY
libpmix2t64 5.0.1-4.1build1 -             deb    CVE-2023-41915   High
My attempts to install CDO on the Alpine base image were:

I attempted to install cdo directly from the Alpine package repositories using apk add cdo. The package was not found in the repository, leading to the error: cdo (no such package).

As cdo was not available in the Alpine repositories, so I tried to install it from the source. This involved downloading the cdo source code, configuring, compiling, and installing it. During the compilation of cdo, I encountered several issues, such as missing header files (sys/cdefs.h). These errors indicate that some development libraries or headers required for compiling cdo are missing or not correctly installed. Multiple attempts to resolve these missing dependencies by adding various development packages (musl-dev, libc-dev, linux-headers, etc.) still resulted in compilation errors. The errors persisted despite ensuring that all relevant development tools and libraries were included.


Do you have any suggestions on how to solve the vulnerability on the Ubuntu:24.04 image or how to install CDO on the Alpine base image? I prefer a solution that solves the vulnerability on the Ubuntu:24.04-based image, as I still don't know if the final image based on Alpine will not have other vulnerabilities.

I'd be shocked if you can find a software stack with no security vulnerabilities at all.  It sounds like your security scanner might not correctly find the Alpine packages, but it seems extremely likely that, whatever you're using, there are unpatched CVEs in it.  This question also sounds like you're trying to package a piece of software in an image, more than programming per se.
